# Does Google and Yandex index existed path, if I allow it in robots.txt, but other pages don't contain links in it

Tags: seo, robots.txt

I have some page, say `/hidden_archive`, that are not referenced from any other pages.

And I include in my `robots.txt` next line `Allow: /hidden_archive`.

Will search crawlers index that page?

Comment: The most reliable way of making sure that a page will be indexed by Google is to add it to sitemap page <http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sitemaps> and submit it via Webmaster Tools <https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/home?hl=en>

Answer (score 1):

I'd say: No.

Why can't you add some links on your pages? No one claims they must be visible to humans...

Answer (score 1):

No, crawlers will not index that page unless it's linked from somewhere (even different website)